# Difference Between parcelable and Serialization?

Tags: java, android, serialization, parcelable

can anyone please explain me what it means by the performance issue the serialization encounters and make the Parcelable an efficient way rather than serialization in android to pass an object from one activity to another.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Check [out this link][1]

Hope it helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11078000/2345913

Comment: Hi Crusader, the read this one and it says --The preferred technique is Parcelable since it doesn't impact the performance.But I am not understanding how serialization impacts the performance

Comment: Thanks Waqas. I am sorry for creating a duplicate question,

Comment: Hi Waqas,Thanks for mentioning it. But clear explanation is been provided in the underlying link provide by nbe_42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read a nice blogpost about it : http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/