# Difference between Serializable, Parcelable in Android

Tags: android, parcelable, serializable

1].What is the difference between **Serializable, Parcelable**?

2].Can I implement Both Interfaces in Pojo Class?,If answer is **No**,what is the reason for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077907/what-is-difference-between-parcelable-and-serialization-used-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550670/benefit-of-using-parcelable-instead-of-serializing-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Parcelable** and **Serialization** are used for marshaling and unmarshaling Java objects.

More details : http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/

Comment: thanks for your reply.from this link i came to know that implementing either one interface is Enough...am i right?

Comment: Yes.. jfyi : but for Android Parcelable is better in Android developement

Comment: how come u saying Parcelable is better in Android..Only difference I found between those two is "Speed  Issue"..other than this anyother reason is there?

Comment: Yes.. Main thing is speed because it's is specially created for android also. And it's also improve performance b'cz it's speedy.