# Safe/Easy way to update Parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable

Is there a common practice that can prevent missout fields in `writeToParcel` and `Parcel contructor` when introducing new member variables to a class that already implemented Parcelable?

The reason is because currently I have hundreds of pojo classes that is constantly changing (adding/renaming fields) during the development phase. I find it tedious to update Parceable every time I make changes, especially new developers who joined the team tends to miss out this change.

The legacy java serialization seems to have this well taken care.

Comment: Meet the same problem. My way is remove the function and re-generate by the android studio.

Comment: Just Remove all your previous Parceable implementation. And again extend ur class with "implements Parceable". ALT + ENTER the implementation and its regenerated including the new variables you added.

Comment: @DAgrawal yes, that would be ideal if the developer remembers to do this every time. Question is what if he misses out?

Comment: @YouQi : Then you miss out that variable and that wont be parceable , cant be careless about it, The moment you add a new variable, do as above.

Comment: hence my question. the process used to be a single line change back in the serialization day. but now with Parcelable, every time I introduce a new field, I need to go thru the class to remove the `static Creator`, the `describerContent` method, the `writeToParcel`, and the `Constructor with Parcel argument` just so I can re-implement the whole thing by android studio? is there any better way in doing this or this is the only way for now?

Comment: Only way for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisiting this in 2021. We can simply use the `Parcelize` annotation:

```kotlin
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class Headlines(
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
): Parcelable
```

Further reading: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize

Answer (score 3):

Place your cursor on your class name which implements Parcelable interface and press alt+enter(option+enter in mac) meant for Projet quick fix. Click on the option called Replace Parcelable Implementation.This does the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and update a parcelable class easily with **NO HARD CODING** approach and **Android studio 4.1.2** can do it for you just in a few seconds !!!

**Update an existing parcelable class:**

***Step 1:*** If you need to add some new field in your existing class then you need to remove the previous `writeToParcel` and `describeContents` methods and `CREATOR` class.

***Step 2:*** Implement parcelable methods by pressing `Alt+Enter` for windows and `Option+Enter` for mac but you will find that the `writeToParcel` is empty for the first time -

[image]

***Step 3:*** Then you will find that your class name is red now. So you need to add the `CREATOR` class as well as to fill the empty `writeToParcel` by pressing `Alt+Enter` for windows and `Option+Enter` for mac -

[image]

Finally, you will see your class will be a fully parcelable class now !!!
To get more insight please see my real [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66306363/7200133).

Comment: If you're posting [exactly the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66306363/4657412) to two questions, that usually means that you should flag on of them as a duplicate instead

Comment: @DavidW No, actually context is different

Comment: And the answer is not exactly the same, I did some modifications based on his requirement.